# export into a file in python

Tags: python, list, file

I have many lists (2550) like this, which are made by for loop (lists are not nested):

```
[' id   "ENS001" ', ' name   "EGSB"  ', ' Trans   "TTP" ']
```

Each list corresponds to each factor I have (there are 2550 factors). Each list has 3 pairs, and first item of each pair is common in all lists. So, in the lists there are 3 common characters which would be the column names. In each pair, items are separated from each other but I don't know it is tab or space because they were separated in original file.

I want to create a file with 3 columns and 2550 rows (in addition to the first row which would be column names) and each row would be the information of each list (meaning 2nd item of each pair which corresponds to each factor).

Answer (score 0):

let us assume that you have a parent list in which you have all these 2550 lists.

```
parent_list = [[' id "ENS001" ', ' name "EGSB" ', ' Trans "TTP" ']]

print "id\tname\ttrans\n"
for lst in parent_list:
    print lst[0].split()[1],"\t",lst[1].split()[1],"\t",lst[2].split()[1]
```

This makes sense ?

```
id              name            rans

"ENS001"        "EGSB"         "TTP"
```

However you can also use a .write() method instead of print function to write the contents to a file, after opening that file, see file handling in python.